# Change a button color and than change it back with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```html
<div id="ext">01</div>
```

How do I add a button that changes the color of the `div` to some color on click and changes it back on click again?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: For reference, a helpful format or template for asking questions is putting your content into these sections:  Desired Behavior, Actual Behavior, What I’ve Tried (which includes code samples and links to research you have done about the question). Often you will find using this approach solves the question before you post it!  Good luck with your programming journey!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or for a full case here with jquery

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $("#ext").toggleClass("yourColor");
  });
});
</script>
<style>
    .yourColor{
        background-color: green;
        color:blue;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ext" class="">01</div>
    <button id="btn">toggle</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working, thank you so much. If i make multiple numbers with the same function all change together, there's a way with one function i change only one div?

Comment: @Guilherme I've updated my answer to add support for multiple `div`s.

Comment: that really depends on where the div is. If it is right before or right after then fine you can use the prev() function. Otherwise if you want to use the same function for all the buttons  you need a metadata attribute like <button class="btn" number="1">and to change the divs id acordingly ie... <div id="ext1" class="">01</div> . Then change the function to $(".btn").click(function(){
    $("#ext"+$(this).attr('number')).toggleClass("yourColor");
  });

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `click` event listener on a button that toggles a class which applies a color:

```js
$(btn).on('click', function(){ $(ext).toggleClass('with-color') })
```

```css
.with-color{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ext">01</div>
<button id="btn">Toggle Color</button>
```

If you prefer a solution without jQuery:

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  ext.classList.toggle('with-color');
})
```

```css
.with-color{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="ext">01</div>
<button id="btn">Toggle Color</button>
```

---

If you want the button to be able to toggle the class once, you can store the times the button has been clicked and stop toggling when it is clicked more than twice:

```js
var count = 0;
$(btn).on('click', function() {
  if (count != 2) $(ext).toggleClass('with-color'), count++
})
```

```css
.with-color {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ext">01</div>
<button id="btn">Toggle Color</button>
```

---

If you have multiple numbers, just get the closest previous `div` on button click:

```js
$(btn).on('click', function(){ $(this).prev('div').first().toggleClass('with-color') })
```

```css
.with-color{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ext">01</div>
<button id="btn">Toggle Color</button>
<div id="ext">02</div>
<button id="btn">Toggle Color</button>
<div id="ext">03</div>
<button id="btn">Toggle Color</button>
```